# Is there a way to export syntax color settings from one Xcode installation to a new one?

Tags: data-transfer, xcode, settings, color, preferences

I have installed a new XCode 4 on a machine and I'd like to copy/paste the syntax coloring settings from the first one to the new one. How may I do this ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Custom syntax color themes are located in

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
```

(Note that this directory may not exist if you've not yet modified any of your themes or haven't created a custom theme of your own, but will be created as soon as you do.)

The files have a `.dvtcolortheme` extension. Simply retrieve the file from that directory and copy it into the same directory on another machine.

---

I quite like Ethan Schoonover's [***Solarized* themes**](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized); I find them to be very readable and easy on the eyes, and can be installed as explained above.

Comment: Still valid in Xcode 9!

Comment: Also valid in Xcode 10!!

Comment: I only get `xccolortheme` file, change extension `.xccolortheme` to `.dvtcolortheme` work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer while looking how to move the new (at the time of writing this answer) Civic theme in Xcode 8 to Xcode 7.3. Now themes are bundled inside of the Xcode application's bundle at following path:

```
Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FontAndColorThemes
```

Also Xcode8 theme has extension `xccolortheme` while Xcode7.3 has `dvtcolortheme`. From my experience - it's safe change the extension without modifying the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode Version 11.6 (11E708), the file extension for color themes is `xccolortheme`.

The path to the included themes is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTUserInterfaceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FontAndColorThemes
```

---

The path to a user's custom themes is the same as in the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17677/20728):

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/FontAndColorThemes/
```

---

To *install* a custom theme, you can simply drag the `xccolortheme` file into the folder for custom themes; quit Xcode, then restart Xcode. The theme will now appear in Xcode's Preferences for *Fonts & Colors*.

Comment: where is the location of custom themes in xcode 12 and above?

Comment: As far as I can tell, @AriSteinfeld, custom themes are still in the same place. I'm using Xcode 13.2.1, and everything's still in these same directories.

Answer (score 0):

With Themeinstaller, you can just open .dvtcolortheme files and they will be installed in your Xcode folder.

In case you wanted some new themes there are many to be found on codethemes.net, having Themeinstaller, you can install them, just by clicking "install" under any of your choice.

Comment: How do you get the theme from your current Xcode?